# Do I use simple past or past progressive when describing someone being hungry?

Tags: past-tense

> 1. When Taro had walked far from the seashore, he felt tired and  hungry.
> 2. When Taro had walked far from the seashore, he was feeling tired and hungry.

Which amongst the above two sentences is correct? With reference to perfect tenses, are there any specific rules as in which tense should be used for the other part of the sentence? Please help me with a few examples for the same.

Comment: They both sound a bit odd, but that’s because the two clauses don’t match. “When he had walked far” is a state that endures over a period of time, and so is “he felt/was feeling hungry”. In “When X, then Y”, we normally expect one of the two to represent a **point** in time. So “When Taro reached the village [point], he felt/was feeling tired and hungry” is fine, and so is “When Taro had walked far from the seashore, he stopped [point], feeling tired and hungry”. _Feel_ generally describes states, not points in time, so either simple past or past progressive work fine.

Comment: The title question is completely different from the question asked here, which uses _feel_, not _be_. They aren't the same at all.

Answer (score 1):

As is very often the case with aspectual questions in English, neither is more correct than the other, and there is no difference whatever in the objective reality that they describe. The difference is **entirely** in how you are relating the events to other events, situtations, or viewpoints in the narrative. The second focuses on his feelings as a continuing state, and might well be followed by things that happened while he had those feelings. The first does not treat them as a continuing state, and might pass on to what happened afterwards, for example; but it doesn't preclude continuing with things that happened while he had those feelings.